# change state of image button from background service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-imagebutton

with my app you can start its service by pressing the Image button within the mainActivity. pressing the imageButton will change its image from a red button to a green one and vice a versa when pressed, which will also stop the service.
The only way to change the imageButton from the red one (indicating app is off) and green one (app is on) is by pressing the button.

what i have no created is a broadcast receiver that on receive can start my apps service without evening going into the app and pressing the button. the only problem is that i cant seem to sync the imageButton (red/off or green/on) with the state of the service. 
when the service gets switched on externally from the onReceive in the broadcast receiver, when i go into the app its still red.

I would so you my code, but i'm sorry to say its all over the place and not where start with putting bits of it on here. sorry, not usually like this.
basically I have a mainActivity with a ImageButton and a Broadcast Receiver. then a service class. any ideas how to sync up the two?

I tried using a getters and setters but they didn't seem to work.
I need the imageButton to change in onCreate, onResume. its already working in the onReceive of the broadcast Receiver.

the variable i'm using in the service class to keep track of the state of the service doesn't seem to persist. i set false at the top then when the service is started i set it to true, but then in the activity when ever i call Service.getMode() it always returns false. would sharedPreferences do the trick?

I would be very grateful for any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes..sharedpreference will work.